# Why does my exit process execute before the loop ends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I came from Ruby, so I spent a day to figure out why process.exit(1) executes before loop end. Any ideas what I need to change to make it work?

```
export default async () => {
    const workbook = Xlsx.readFile(path.join(__dirname, './excel.xlsx'));
    const data = Xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets.Extract, {
        header: getHeaderFor(workbook.Sheets.Extract),
    });
    await data.map(async (product, index) => {
        if (index < 6) return;
        await processProduct(product);
    });
    process.exit(1);
};
```

Comment: What's processProduct? What's `data`? Is it array? Use `await Promise.all(data...)` instead of `await data...`.

Comment: @estus data is an array. Promise.all run in parallels, when I need a sequence.

Comment: Then it's like the answer suggests. Don't use `map` for iteration, it produces an array of promises and is supposed to be used with Promise.all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that If you replace:

```
await data.map(async (product, index) => {
    if (index < 6) return;
    await processProduct(product);
});
```

with

```
for (let i = 6; i < data.length; i++) {
  await processProduct(data[i]);
}
```

your problem will be solved.

**Some explanation:** javascript's map function is creating new array from source array when it is calling a callback function for each element of the source array and pushing the returned value of the callback into the result array. In this case `await data.map(...` is invalid statement, because the result of `map` is array. To fix this it is possible to wrap the result in `await Promise.all(data.map(...))` or to use a normal `for` loop. You can use the first case when you don't care about concurrency and the second case when you want to achieve sequential order.

Comment: It works, but ESlint says `ESLint: Unexpected 'await' inside a loop.`

Comment: @Meliborn Then disable than ESLint rule? await in a loop isn't bad when you're aware that it makes your async tasks run in series. It's flagged by ESLint because it can be used accidentally when Promise.all should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

While @codtex's answer will work, it will also result in poor performance since each iteration of the loop will wait until the previous iteration. What you really want to do is collect all of the Promises, and then wait for them to finish:

```
const promises = data.map((product, index) => {
  if (index < 6) return;
  return processProduct(product);
});

await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: I know, but I need sequence running, one by one, to prevent condition race.